Using `inferences` with comparison and transform arguments
I'd like to use the inferences function to do some bootstrapping for a quantity which requires me to use comparison and transform arguments in avg_comparisons.
However, when I pass the output of avg_comparisons to inferences, I'm met with an assertion error.  Here is a minimal example
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

set.seed(0)
n <- 500
trt <- rep(0:1, each=500)
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2*x + 1 + 0.5*trt + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3)



d <- data.frame(x, trt, y)
fit <- lm(y~trt + x, data=d)

avg_comparisons(
  fit,
  variables = 'trt',
  comparison = 'lnratioavg',
  transform = 'exp'
) %>% 
  inferences(method='boot')
#> Error: Assertion failed. One of the following must apply:
#>  * checkmate::check_choice(x): Must be element of set {'exp','ln'}, but
#>  * is not atomic scalar
#>  * checkmate::check_function(x): Must be a function, not 'list'

Created on 2024-05-04 with reprex v2.1.0
What are these assertion errors referring to and how can I achieve what I want?

This is a bug. It should be fixed in version 0.19.0.8 on Github.
See: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues/1115
